# Ruby on Rails - passing params into 301 redirect in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I want to change my existing 'game' routing inside routes.rb, but because of SEO I need also to setup 301 redirect for old links.

My old routing:

```
match 'games/:permalink/:id/(:page)' => 'games#show'
```

New routing:

```
match 'gierki/:permalink/(:page)' => 'games#show'
```

Here is redirection which I tried to to do:

```
match 'games/:permalink/:id/(:page)' => redirect {|params| "/gierki/#{params[:permalink]}" + params[:page].nil? ? "" : "/#{params[:page]}" }
```

Above redirect is not working, here is an error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error occurs while routing?

Comment: I am sure, answer below worked great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try making it like this:

```
match 'games/:permalink/:id/(:page)' => redirect {|params,request| "/gierki/#{params[:permalink]}" + params[:page].nil? ? "" : "/#{params[:page]}" }
```

And see if it works.

Comment: How does this redirect with 301?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection -- routing redirect is a 301