# Redirect all routes in a path to another path and keep rest of the URL intact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I want to rename a resource in a Rails app, and have all the old routes redirect to the new ones for backwards compatibility with old links. For example, rename 'user' to 'member' and have all arbitrary route such as `example.com/user/1/posts/all?order=date` redirected to `example.com/member/1/posts/all?order=date`

How can I set up the `routes.rb` file to redirect all paths to another route, but maintaining all the path params after what I'm looking to match (including url params)?

It should also work, for example, for `example.com/user/no/real/path?foo=bar`, which should redirect to `example.com/member/no/real/path?foo=bar`

Basically I want to redirect any `path` to `path.sub(/\A\/user/, '/member')`

I checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627796/893510), but it does not seem to work with the parameters.

This is the solution I have so far, pretty awful:

```
get 'user/*path', to: redirect{|params, request|
    path = params[:path].sub('/user', '/member')
    params = request.params.except(:path).map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')
    if params.presence
      "#{path}?#{params}"
    else
      path
    end
  }
```

Comment: Did you set up the original route as `resources :users`?

Comment: I did, but it includes several custom member and collection routes, so that can't be used to solve the issue

Comment: Did you try this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4814366/1512956

Comment: Yes, the problem there is with the parameters, they are not passed on to the redirected route.

Comment: Have you tried any of these? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection , http://stackoverflow.com/a/10815691/978697

Comment: Yes, the issue is always with passing on the URL parameters

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution would be helpful.

```
get 'user/*path', to: redirect{| _params, request| request.url.sub('user', 'member')}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?